# Настройка триггеров в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь изменить стандартное выделение кнопки

```
ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate();
var t = new Trigger();
ct.Triggers = t.Property
```

Я знаю, что надо Property изменять, но не знаю что дальше писать
Кто-нибудь подскажет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно определить стиль в `App.xaml` и доставать его с помощью

```
MyButton.Style = FindResource("MyButtonStyle") as Style;
```

---

Пример стиля для изменения стандартного выделения кнопки:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Здесь надо поработать над переопределенным Template кнопки

Comment: да я знаю как это в xaml делать
у меня кнопки программно создаются
при определенных условиях

Comment: [Можно ссылаться на ресурс](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199424/how-to-set-the-style-programatically). Правлю свой ответ. Так подойдет или все-равно нет?

Comment: Да, вполне подойдет